# angular-bootstrap-calendar dependency issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using angular-bootstrap-calendar: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar

Using the Demo Mark up provided on that page, I am receiving the following error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=alertProvider%20%3C-%20alert%20%3C-%20TestCal

After so reading I think this has something to do with dependencies, though after reading and re-reading the code the dependencies appear to be in the correct order. I was considering version, though I am unable to find a comprehensive source that discusses version mismatch between the dependencies.

> Bower.json

```
    {
     "name": "ASP.NET",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
           "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
           "jquery": "2.1.4",
           "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
           "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.4",
           "angular-bootstrap-calendar": "0.19.3",
           "angular": "1.5.0",
           "font-awesome": "4.5.0",
           "moment": "2.12.0",
           "interact.js": "1.2.6",
           "angular-bootstrap": "1.2.4",
           "angular-touch": "1.5.0",
           "angular-animate": "1.5.0"
       }
    }
```

> Script load order on HTML

```
<link href="~/lib/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/interact.js/dist/interact.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/calandar.js"></script>
```

> HTML Markup

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
<div ng-controller="TestCal as vm">
    <h2 class="text-center">{{ vm.calendarTitle }}</h2>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">

                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                        mwl-date-modifier
                        date="vm.viewDate"
                        decrement="vm.calendarView">
                    Previous
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default"
                        mwl-date-modifier
                        date="vm.viewDate"
                        set-to-today>
                    Today
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                        mwl-date-modifier
                        date="vm.viewDate"
                        increment="vm.calendarView">
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br class="visible-xs visible-sm">

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'year'">Year</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'month'">Month</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'week'">Week</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'day'">Day</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <mwl-calendar events="vm.events"
                  view="vm.calendarView"
                  view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
                  view-date="vm.viewDate"
                  on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
                  on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
                  edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'"
                  delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'"
                  on-edit-event-click="vm.eventEdited(calendarEvent)"
                  on-delete-event-click="vm.eventDeleted(calendarEvent)"
                  cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen"
                  day-view-start="06:00"
                  day-view-end="22:00"
                  day-view-split="30"
                  cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)">
    </mwl-calendar>

    <br><br><br>

    <h3 id="event-editor">
        Edit events
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                ng-click="vm.events.push({title: 'New event', type: 'important', draggable: true, resizable: true})">
            Add new
        </button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </h3>

    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Starts at</th>
                <th>Ends at</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="event in vm.events track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           ng-model="event.title">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="event.type" class="form-control">
                        <option value="important">Important</option>
                        <option value="warning">Warning</option>
                        <option value="info">Info</option>
                        <option value="inverse">Inverse</option>
                        <option value="success">Success</option>
                        <option value="special">Special</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               readonly
                               uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
                               ng-model="event.startsAt"
                               is-open="event.startOpen"
                               close-text="Close">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-default"
                                    ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'startOpen', event)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <uib-timepicker ng-model="event.startsAt"
                                    hour-step="1"
                                    minute-step="15"
                                    show-meridian="true">
                    </uib-timepicker>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               readonly
                               uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
                               ng-model="event.endsAt"
                               is-open="event.endOpen"
                               close-text="Close">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-default"
                                    ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'endOpen', event)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <uib-timepicker ng-model="event.endsAt"
                                    hour-step="1"
                                    minute-step="15"
                                    show-meridian="true">
                    </uib-timepicker>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger"
                            ng-click="vm.events.splice($index, 1)">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

> Javascript to handle Angular ~/js/calandar.js

```
  angular.module('TestApp', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('TestCal', function (moment, alert) {

var vm = this;
vm.calendarView = 'month';
vm.viewDate = new Date();
vm.events = [
  {
      title: 'An event',
      type: 'warning',
      startsAt: moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').add(8, 'hours').toDate(),
      endsAt: moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'week').add(9, 'hours').toDate(),
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true
  }, {
      title: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> <span class="text-primary">Another event</span>, with a <i>html</i> title',
      type: 'info',
      startsAt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
      endsAt: moment().add(5, 'days').toDate(),
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true
  }, {
      title: 'This is a really long event title that occurs on every year',
      type: 'important',
      startsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
      endsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(19, 'hours').toDate(),
      recursOn: 'year',
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true
  }
];

vm.isCellOpen = true;

vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    event[field] = !event[field];
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the controller field.

```
 .controller('TestCal', function (moment, alert) {};
```

alert called on a dependency that was not there. It was designed for throwing up modals, removing this makes the calendar work as required.

```
 .controller('TestCal', function (moment) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

**mwl-Calendar** needs to use the "alert" service/factory.
Add the following (factory) to your code beside to the controller:

```js
.factory('alert', function($uibModal) {
            function show(action, event) {
              return $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'Views/Scheduler/modalCalendar.html',
                controller: function() {
                  var vm = this;
                  vm.action = action;
                  vm.event = event;
                },
                controllerAs: 'vm'
              });
            }
            return {
              show: show
            };
          })
```

It worked for me, hopefully this will help!